# chrome flash EOL on linux/ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, flash

There are multiple blogs on how to make flash work post EOL for sites or firmware console that have failed to migrate before EOL.

- downgrade to google-chrome 87.x
- build `mms.cfg` and put in appropriate google-chrome config directory

To this extent I want to run this patch in a VM (Ubuntu 20.4.1 on VirtualBox 6.1.6) to ensure that my actual machines are unto date and fully patched.  However I'm finding patch works on my MacOS host but not in Ubuntu VM.  The *run once* button never appears and flash component in webpage shows *download failed*

To remove potential for typos - I've coded in python with a YaML config file.  **Why does this not work in google-chrome on Ubuntu?**

#### chrome.py

```
import re, shutil, subprocess, yaml, click
from pathlib import Path
import platform

def cmd(cmd:str="ls -al", assertfail=True) :
    up = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, close_fds=True)
    str = [o.rstrip().decode() for o in up.stdout]
    exitcode = up.wait()
    if assertfail: assert exitcode == 0, f"[{exitcode}] {cmd} {str}"
    return exitcode,  str

@click.command()
@click.option("--uninstall", default=False, is_flag=True, help="uninstall google chrome")
def main(uninstall):
    click.secho(f"{platform.system()}")
    with open(Path.cwd().joinpath("chrome.yaml")) as f: config = yaml.safe_load(f)

    if platform.system()=="Linux":
        if uninstall:
            e, out = cmd("sudo apt-get purge -y google-chrome-stable")
            print(out)

        cdeb = Path.cwd().joinpath(f"chrome-{config['version']}.deb")
        # download required version of chrome if it has not already been downloaded
        if not cdeb.exists():
            e, out = cmd(f"wget --no-verbose -O {cdeb} http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_{config['version']}_amd64.deb")
            print(out)

        # check wanted version of chrome is installed
        e, iv = cmd("google-chrome --version", assertfail=False)
        iv = iv[0] if e==0 else "0.0.0.0"
        vre = re.compile("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")
        iv = re.search(vre, iv)[0]
        wv = re.search(vre, config["version"])[0]
        click.secho(f"installed: {iv} wanted: {wv} same: {iv==wv}",bg="cyan")
        if iv!=wv:
            e, out = cmd(f"sudo apt install -y {cdeb}")
            print(out)

        # make sure required locations of adobe config files exist
        p2 = Path.home().joinpath(".config/google-chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System/")
    elif platform.system()=="Darwin":
        p2 = Path.home().joinpath("Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Pepper Data/Shockwave Flash/System/")

    else:
        click.secho(f"unknow operating system {platform.system}")
        exit(1)
    if not p2.exists():
        p2.mkdir(parents=True)
    
    # build adobe flash config file
    mmsf = Path.cwd().joinpath("mms.cfg")
    with open(mmsf, "w") as f:
        for l in config["base"]: f.write(f"{l}\n")
        for u in config["urls"]:
            for l in [f"{k}={v}{u}\n" for p in config["urlkeys"] for k,v in p.items()]: f.write(l)

    # distribute adobe flash config file
    shutil.copy(mmsf, p2)
    click.secho(str(p2.joinpath("mms.cfg")), bg="blue", bold=True, reverse=True)
    with open(p2.joinpath("mms.cfg")) as f:
        click.secho(f.read(), bg="blue")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### chrome.yaml

```
base:
  - EnableAllowList=1
  - EOLUninstallDisable=1
  - ErrorReportingEnable=1
  # - TraceOutputFileEnable=1
  # - PolicyFileLog=1
  - AllowListPreview=1
  - TraceOutputEcho=1
urls:
  - codegeek.net
  - ultrasounds.com
  - photobox.co.uk
  - secure.photobox.com
  - serving.photos.photobox.com
urlkeys:
  - AllowListUrlPattern: "*://*."
  - WhitelistUrlPattern: "*://*."
  - AllowListUrlPattern: "*://"
  - WhitelistUrlPattern: "*://"
 # https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-stable
 # 87 - last version  with flash bundled
version: 87.0.4280.141-1
```

Comment: Same issue for me. Also Chromium shows 'this plugin is not supported.'

Comment: I never got to work on ubuntu - I rescued the content I had on a commercial photos website using a Mac OS build of google-chrome.  I wanted to do on a sandboxed ubuntu machine for obvious reasons.